# Automatic and seamless way to install a JVM

Tags: java, installation, jvm, java-runtime-compiler

i am programming an app for desktop targeting only windows, i would like a way to install the JVM automatically but with an additional option, i want the JVM to be a part of the app which mean you cannot uninstall the JVM and the only way to do it is by uninstalling my entire app and this way i don't have to deal with customer's complaining after deleting JVM
the only way i know to do that is by making a private JRE and applying special paths to it.
is there any simple and direct ways to wrap the installation process with the automatic installation of the JVM ?

Comment: Depends on the Java version. OpenJDK is free and can be bundled with your application. When you use Java modules, you can use [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm) to create an optimized runtime image containing JDK and application modules, but only those you actually use. Installing such an image reduces to extracting that directory to some target location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) tool.

It is available since Java 14 and is "able to produce a native package in a platform-specific format".

You can use it for example to package an application as .exe/.msi on windows.

Example:

```
package -n yourApplicationName -p ỳourModulePath -m your.module.name/com/example/YourMainClass
```

This will create for example a .deb package on linux with the name yourApplicationName, containing an runtime image with exactly the required dependencies.